# Publish WPF project

Tags: .net, wpf

I followed the instruction on Microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli to publish a single file WPF app as follow:

1. Add this code to the project csproj file (with net4.0 instead as my project was initially setup with .NET target framework 4.8)

[image]

2. Runn Command `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained false`

However, the publish was not successful because this can only work for .NET 5 and above (as per my research). I could not find any other alternative to publish one single file app. So, my question is:

1. Is there any other way around that can help me achieve this? I tried upgrading from .NET target framework 4.8 to 7 but there were many errors occurred after the upgrade and I could not resolve them all. For instance, one of the error was my installed package was gone and when I tried to re-install it, it keeps saying `package source mapping is off` in the Nuget Package tab. I added Nuget.org in the mapping settings like Microsoft website shows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping but it still shows same message `package source mapping is off`. So I guess I will just give up on the upgrade.
2. If I have no choice but to publish with multiple files, how can I do that? I found a `publish` option when right-click on the project name. Is that the right way to do?
3. If I publish with more than one file, how can I setup a live version update mechanism? I will have to publish the app and give it to the clients but the app should be maintained and updated frequently.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As you said, single file apps are not supported by .NET FW 4.8. You’ll either have to convert the solution to work with a later .NET version (which may take quite a bit of work), or provide the program in multiple files. Creating an installer might be useful. Depending what “live update” means that’s another thing. Is a new installer sufficient?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am still very new to desktop applications and I didn't know about installer solution so I'll look into that as well. Regarding "live update", it means, for instance, the user starts the app and it'll check via an API to see if there is any new version available. If yes, the app will automatically update the app without user having to download and install again.

Comment: For that kind of update you’ll need to add the functionality yourself, just like with a single file application. There’s nothing built in to my knowledge.

Comment: BTW the `dotnet publish` with runtime identifier `linux-x64` cannot be successful in any way with WPF

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give it a try to upgrade it to target framework .NET 7. The main issues I got is the package mapping https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping. I just needed to add nuget.org source for each installed package. Got some other issues but I was able to resolve it. So I'll close my question. Thank you all for commenting and helping out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).